# Why does IntelliJ sometimes throw an unused warning but sometimes not?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, warnings

I have many Java classes with two constructors:

1. a private constructor with no arguments and with unused warning suppression called by gson;
2. a public constructor with arguments.

In one class IntelliJ informs me with a warning that the public constructor is never used. In all other classes there isn't the warning, but if I click Find Usage for the method it displays "Nothing found in project files".

Why is there a warning in some cases and not in others? How can I make IntelliJ always behave in the same way?

This is the class where the public constructor throws the warning:

```
public class ShopMarketAction extends Action {

    private Boolean inRow = null;
    private Integer index = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused") // Called by gson
    private ShopMarketAction() {
        super(ActionType.SHOP_MARKET);
    }

    // THIS METHOD THROWS AN UNUSED WARNING
    public ShopMarketAction(boolean inRow, int index) {
        super(ActionType.SHOP_MARKET);
        this.inRow = inRow;
        this.index = index;
    }

}
```

This is an example class where the public constructor doesn't throw the warning:

```
public class ProductionAction extends Action {

    private Integer cardIndex = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused") // Called by gson
    private ProductionAction() {
        super(ActionType.PRODUCE);
    }

    // THIS METHOD DOESN'T THROW THE WARNING BUT IS NEVER USED
    public ProductionAction(int cardIndex) {
        super(ActionType.PRODUCE);
        this.cardIndex = cardIndex;
    }

}
```

I specify that in both classes the method is not used yet.

The Action class that both classes extends:

```
public abstract class Action {

    @SuppressWarnings({"unused", "FieldCanBeLocal"})
    private final ActionType type; // Used by gson

    protected Action(ActionType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

The ActionType enum:

```
public enum ActionType {
    SHOP_MARKET, PRODUCE;
}
```

[image: Warning]

[image: No Warning]

[image: No Usage]

Comment: You forgot to include the class in question.

Comment: Public members can be accesses by anyone, right? So if the member is public we cannot conclude that the member is unused, because separately compiled code may access the member, right? *Mostly* right, but if the class itself is a private nested class, then only code in the current compilation unit can access it, so the members aren't truly "public".

Comment: I edited the question and I added two example classes.

Comment: Both the classes are public and in the same package

Comment: Can you produce an example we can verify?

Comment: @HenryTwist I added the class which is extended by both classes if that's what you mean

Comment: Well I still don't have `ActionType` so I can't reproduce it. You can take a look into what a [mre] is for some pointers.

Comment: However, testing it without `ActionType`, I can't reproduce the issue. They both show the warnings as expected.

Comment: I added ActionType and some screenshots of the problem. I tried to recreate the classes and to clear cache but the problem persists

Comment: I've copied your whole example, but I still get the unused warning on both constructors I'm afraid.

Comment: I found what cause the problem: I have a directory with an xml file used by another program to generete uml and IntelliJ consider a method written in that file as used. Do you know how can I avoid that? Is it possible to exclude non java files or a spesific directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what causes the problem: I have a non-Java file (an UXF file created by another application) which contains the name of all these methods and for some reason IntelliJ consider them as used because of this.

Comment: Please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue if case you consider this as a bug. Thank you

Comment: @OlgaKlisho Ok thank you, but I don't know if it is a bug or not

Comment: In case you attach the little code sample illustratinng the case to the issue, we'll investigate 